# Something bad happened - Browser specific?

Tags: support

I’m intermittently getting an error Something bad happened when adding comments and answering questions.  It doesn’t happen that often but it’s very annoying when you type a lengthy answer only to get the "SBH of death" and lose everything I’ve typed.

My question is, does anyone know if this is browser specific?  Or better yet is there any browsers not affected by this problem?  It’s just frustrating answering the same thing twice.

EDIT:
The majority of the time I'm using my cellular card.

Edit #2:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Scott>tracert -d stackoverflow.com

Tracing route to stackoverflow.com [69.59.196.211]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    91 ms    92 ms    98 ms  
  2   227 ms    92 ms    99 ms  
  3    94 ms    92 ms    99 ms  
  4   183 ms   101 ms    88 ms  68.28.159.5
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6   130 ms    95 ms    98 ms  68.28.157.69
  7    90 ms    92 ms    91 ms  144.223.137.225
  8   124 ms   106 ms   115 ms  144.232.18.212
  9   159 ms   150 ms   145 ms  144.232.20.156
 10   163 ms   144 ms   150 ms  144.232.6.122
 11   150 ms   152 ms   160 ms  204.181.35.194
 12   150 ms   131 ms   167 ms  66.206.80.21
 13   163 ms   150 ms   163 ms  12.111.189.106
 14   219 ms   158 ms   151 ms  69.59.218.2
 15   167 ms   152 ms   161 ms  69.59.218.193
 16   156 ms   154 ms   151 ms  69.59.218.226
 17   159 ms   158 ms   161 ms  69.59.196.211

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Ive tried the latest versions of firefox and IE both suffer from this problem, havent tried any others.

Comment: Can you provide a tracert output to our site - I'd like to know if it's related to latency or connection speed.  Please measure while using your cellular card.

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide specific steps to reproduce this issue?  Where are you located geographically?  Does this issue occur during certain times of the day?

**Edit:**  We have upped all timeouts to 15 seconds - they may have been a little low for high latency connections.  Let us know if this helps.

Comment: I had the same on android firefox multiple times. First it happened when I tried to get an account list on MSE, second time on my userpage on unix SE. From the second I have a screenshot, and could even produce a bugreport if you wish.